# Creating Wordpress widget but class not found

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

I'm trying to create a wordpress plugin that just deserve a listing of something everyone don't care but I have to do it

I choose to create widgets but I got an error

Can you help me please ?

PS : I am very very noob

> Fatal error: Class 'Proprietaires_Widget' not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/tests/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php
>   on line 100

I do not see where I could have been wrong

**Code :**

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Zero plugin
Plugin URI: http://zero-plugin.com
Description: Un plugin d'introduction pour le développement sous WordPress
Version: 0.1
Author: Midnight Falcon
Author URI: http://votre-site.com
License: GPL2
*/

class EDL
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        include 'proprietaires.php';
        new Proprietaires();
        add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', array($this, 'modifier_titre'), 10); 
    }

    public function modifier_titre($title)
    {
        return 'EDL' . $title;
    }
}
new EDL();
?>

<?php
class Proprietaires
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter('wp_get_document_title', array($this, 'modify_page_title'), 20) ;
        add_action('widgets_init', function(){register_widget('Proprietaires_Widget');});
    }

    public function modify_page_title($title)
    {
        return  'EDL -  Propriétaires' . $title ;
    }
}
```

```
    public function modify_page_title($title)
    {
        return  'EDL -  Propriétaires' . $title ;
    }
}


<?php
class Proprietaires_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Liste_proprietaires', 'Liste des propriétaires', array('description' => 'Affiche la liste des propriétaires.'));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        echo 'Liste des propriooooos';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is correctly included? Try with `include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/proprietaires.php');`

Comment: Yes, I did it and it works and come back to my first error : 
Fatal error: Class 'Proprietaires_Widget' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tests/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 100 :/

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem myself, it was an error with directories, all the files must go on the plugin folder, thank you for your help Rohan